# Lazy Iterator graph

Tags: java, graph, iterator, traversal, tree-traversal

I am implementing a `hasNext()` function for my own Graph Iterator. My traversals must be breadth-first.

Variables of class `GIterator`:
`Graph g`, `Vertex beginV`, `Set<Vertex> discovered`(the vertexes already iterated with our iterator are added to discovered).

A simple example how you would test the `hasNext()` function:

```
ImplGraph graph = new ImplGraph();
Vertex vertex = new ImplVertex(0);
graph.addVertex(vertex);

Iterator<Vertex> it = new GIterator(graph, vertex);

assertTrue(it.hasNext());
assertSame(vertex, it.next());
assertFalse(it.hasNext());
```

I have tried:

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
   return !(graph.getNeighbours(beginV).isEmpty());
}
```

This will return true if the begin vertex has any neighbors, i.e graph has a next vertex. But obviously this works for only the begin vertex, if my lazy iterator moves on to another vertex, I will need to check if that has any neighbors.

The `Graph` class in my case has functions `getNeighbours` and `getAllVertices`.

I have been stuck for a while now, any ideas?

Comment: At a minimum, your iterator is going to need some kind of state to determine what vertex it's currently on.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth if I return a vertex with the next function, the vertex is added to my variable `discovered` (TreeSet)

Comment: That doesn't tell you where you are, though.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth sometimes I hate coding..

Comment: Take a look at the algorithm for BFS.  Basically, your iterator needs to encapsulate *all* of the state of that algorithm.